# Connect server running on localhost after SSH tunneling

Tags: java

I need to connect DB through SSH tunnel
and connect another application running on localhost.
When tunnel, DB connection is successful but connecting to another application fails.
it says 404 for all the requests.

How can I connect both remote DB and local app ?

Comment: lookup "loop back (network)addressing" the machine itself is 127.0.0.0 and hence never used by anything else , installed server apps usually run as 127.0.0.1 the traditional "localhost" , there is also 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.7 , one app per address, configure your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your data base wiretap with the argument -R.

-R for remote forwarding.

ex:

ssh ipapp -R 1000:localhost{ipBDD}:22

bye